# Illegal assignment from list to map

Tags: map

Apex:code

```
public class mapcollection {
    public static void map_cases()
    {
 Map<Id, Case> mc = new map<Id, Case>();
mc=[select id,status,priority,reason,origin from case];        
          for(id ids:mc.keySet())
          {              
              system.debug(mc);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a `List` to a `Map`, as the error tells you. If you want to use the "magic" functionality that creates a `Map<Id, sObject>` from a `List<sObject>`, you have to do it through the constructor:

```
Map<Id, Case> mc = new Map<Id, Case>(
    [SELECT Id, Status, Priority, Reason, Origin FROM Case]
);
```

Note that doing unrestricted queries is almost always a bad idea that will lead to limits issues.

Comment: yeah i got it .Thank you.